# Can anyone help me decipher this function?

Tags: javascript, dojo

**We are currently working on a small project, we are updating and adding some feature to an existing software and we came across this function that we don't have any idea of what it does.**

```
function myRange(a){var b=false;b=MinMax(a,83300000,83399999,b);b=MinMax(a,83500000,83599999,b);b=MinMax(a,83600000,83699999,b);b=MinMax(a,84000000,84099999,b);b=MinMax(a,84100000,84189999,b);b=MinMax(a,84190000,84199999,b);b=MinMax(a,84200000,84249999,b);b=MinMax(a,84250000,84499999,b);b=MinMax(a,84900000,84983599,b);b=MinMax(a,84983600,84999999,b);b=MinMax(a,86000000,86699999,b);b=MinMax(a,86900000,86999999,b);b=MinMax(a,87400000,87409999,b);b=MinMax(a,88200000,88599999,b);b=MinMax(a,89000000,89499999,b);b=MinMax(a,87300000,87399999,b);b=MinMax(a,22634000,22634999,b);b=MinMax(a,22635000,22635999,b);b=MinMax(a,23139000,23139999,b);b=MinMax(a,23449000,23449999,b);b=MinMax(a,27197000,27197999,b);b=MinMax(a,27226000,27226999,b);b=MinMax(a,27379000,27379999,b);b=MinMax(a,27845000,27845999,b);b=MinMax(a,87200000,87299999,b);b=MinMax(a,87437000,87437999,b);if(b==false){dojo.byId("destino").value="";dojo.byId("destino").focus()}}function MinMax(c,a,d,b){if((c<=d)&&(c>=a)){b=true;return b}else{return b}};
```

Comment: `b = true;` <-- this just sets the local parameter "b", not your variable "b".  This line has no effect.  Avoid naming variables the same as your parameters -- this creates obscure bugs that are very difficult to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myRange` function tests whether its argument `a` lies within any of the ranges 83300000..83399999, 83500000,83599999, etc.; after all those `MinMax` calls, `b` is true if `a` was within one of the ranges and false otherwise.